# What happens to close votes if the user dips below 3000 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, vote-to-close

Suppose a user achieves 3000 reputation points and begins casting close votes. Then, the user downvotes an answer and loses 1 reputation point, falling to 2999. What happens to the close votes? Do they get canceled or do they stay?

Comment: Try. `:-)` 15ch

Comment: FWIW Delete and undelete votes from users who had the privilege in beta remained even after the rep requirements grew upon graduation.

Comment: Daniel, that's one way to test, though I figured you'd just cast a couple of downvotes or something. :-)

Comment: Well I gave away 50 points for a bounty, so I'm down below 3000 rep again, but now I can't see close votes so I don't know if my old close votes are still there. Can somebody check? @DoubleAA

Comment: @MonicaCellio ^

Comment: @Daniel You have to tell us a question you voted to close.

Comment: @Daniel, if you don't want to answer that publicly, post and delete a comment and then let us know to go look.  But, that said, I don't know if we can see who the pending close votes on a question are from, and once a question is closed a change in a closer's privs won't cause it to be re-opened.

Answer (score 4):

The votes still apply. As the user had the prerequisite amount of reputation when they cast the vote, there's no reason to discard it. In fact, doing so would be rather expensive. It's not at all uncommon for someone to reach a new milestone and lose it for a few hours or days until they get a few votes over the line.

This is not really unlike binding votes that a moderator cast holding even after the moderator has stepped down and no longer has the diamond privileged. If you look closely through almost any site, you'll see at least one question that was closed by what appears to be a single ordinary user that doesn't have the necessary reputation to cast a normal close vote.

Hopefully, no votes or reputation were donated to science prior to me answering :)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Some reputation was donated, but only about 20% for the purpose of science :) I put a bounty on a question that I really thought would benefit from some added attention (and it did)